# Retriving models for HasMany relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models

**Time Entry**

```
TimeTray.TimeEntry = DS.Model.extend({
    startTime: DS.attr('date'),
    endTime: DS.attr('date'),
    status: DS.attr('string'),
    offset: DS.attr('number'),
    isDeleted: DS.attr('boolean'),
    task: DS.belongsTo('task'),
    duration: function () {
        return TimeTray.timeController.duration(this.get('startTime'), this.get('endTime'));
    }.property('startTime', 'endTime'),
    title: function () {
        if (this.get('task')) {
            return this.get('task').get('title');
        }
    }.property('task')
});
```

**Task**

```
TimeTray.Task = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    totalTime: function () {
        var timeEntries = this.get('timeEntries')
        for (var entry in timeEntries) {
           var duration =  entry.get('duration')
        }
    }.property('timeEntries'),
    isDeleted: DS.attr('boolean'),
    isRecording: DS.attr('boolean', { defaultValue: false }),
    timeEntries: DS.hasMany('TimeEntry')
});
```

how do i get an array of timeentry entities so that i can calculate the total time spent on a task? the above method doesnt work.

the Time Entry title property works.

Comment: Can I know why my answer was unaccept?

Comment: Hi, my problem wasnt the dynamics of the javascript langauge i know what for( ... in .. ) does, turns out i assumed that if i created a relationship on the timeEntry to the task, ember would automatically add the timeEntry to the task. but it doesnt so i had to return an array with timeEntry id's for the tasks. if you add this to your answer i will gladly re-accept it

Comment: Ok. I missed this. Now the answer is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors in your code:

1- In that foreach

```
...
for (var entry in timeEntries) {
  var duration =  entry.get('duration')
}
...
```

The `for ... in` not work like you expected for arrays, you need to use or `for(var i; i < array.length; i++)` or the `array.forEach(func)`.

2 - In the computed property `totalTime` you will use the `duration` property of the `TimeEntry`, you need to specify that dependency using `property('timeEntries.@each.duration')`.

3 - Probally your `timeEntries` property will be fetched from the server, so you will need to use the `async: true` option, in your definition:

```
timeEntries: DS.hasMany('TimeEntry', { async: true })
```

4 - If your `timeEntries` is always empty, even the data being saved in your database. Make sure that your returned json have the timeEntries ids. For example:

```
{id: 1, title: 'Task 1', timeEntries: [1,2,3] }
```

The changed code is the following:

```
TimeTray.Task = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    totalTime: function () {
        var duration = 0;
        this.get('timeEntries').forEach(function(entry) {
            duration += entry.get('duration')
        });
        return duration;
    }.property('timeEntries.@each.duration'),
    isDeleted: DS.attr('boolean'),
    isRecording: DS.attr('boolean', { defaultValue: false }),
    timeEntries: DS.hasMany('TimeEntry', { async: true })
});
```

And this is the fiddle with this sample working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/9DucM/

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your `totalTime` method is neither summing timeEntry durations nor returning a value. Also your `property` is not set up correctly (use [`@each`](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/)). The correct way of doing this is:

```
totalTime: function () {
    var timeEntries = this.get('timeEntries')
    var duration = 0;
    for (var entry in timeEntries) {
       duration = duration + entry.get('duration');
    }
    return duration;
}.property('timeEntries.@each.duration'),
```

Or, more elegantly using `getEach()` and `reduce()`:

```
totalTime: function () {
    return this.get('timeEntries').getEach('duration').reduce(function(accum, item) {
        return accum + item;
    }, 0);
}.property('timeEntries.@each.duration'),
```